# Android-Java library for debugging

Tags: android

I wonder if there some libraries for enhanced debugging-logging of Android apps. I mean, some facilities, that could ease process of sending logs and creating informational logs (for example, stack-trace + SQLIte database dump or something like that). Realization of such a feature is not that hard, but having some convinience lib would be nice.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) allows you to create log automatically for methods.
[Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) add some automatism to the Log (fill the tag parameters with the class name for example).

You will find many more libraries and infos on [AndroidArsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/57).